# "\t" symbols remain after stripping

Tags: python, tabs

I have a string and some code to strip it:

```
def break_words(stuff):
words = stuff.split(' ')
return sorted(words)
sentence = 'All god'+"\t"+'things come to those who weight.'
print sentence#works as expected
words = break_words(sentence)
print words
```

`sentence` is printed as expected (without the `\t` symbol); but `words` is printed as:

```
['All', 'come', 'god\tthings', 'those', 'to', 'weight.', 'who']
```

How can I remove `\t` from the list?

Comment: Which language is this? Please retag your question.

Comment: Indentations are syntax in python. Your code won't run.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, You'd better check your code indentation before asking questions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace('\t',' ')` or `.expandtabs()`

Then all the new tab characters entered will be changed to spaces.

#### Try This

```
def break_words(stuff):
    words = stuff.replace('\t','').split(' ')
    return sorted(words)

sentence = 'All god'+"\t"+'things come to those who weight.'
print sentence#works as expected
words = break_words(sentence)
print w
```

Output:

```
All god things come to those who weight.
['All', 'come', 'godthings', 'those', 'to', 'weight.', 'who']
```

#### Or this

```
def break_words(stuff):
    words = stuff.replace('\t',' ').split(' ')
    return sorted(words)

sentence = 'All god'+"\t"+'things come to those who weight.'
print sentence#works as expected
words = break_words(sentence)
print words
```

Output:

```
All god things come to those who weight.
['All', 'come', 'god', 'things', 'those', 'to', 'weight.', 'who']
```

### Best Regards :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence = 'All god'+"\t"+'things come to those who weight.'
words = sentence.expandtabs().split(' ')
words = sorted(words)
>> ['All', 'come', 'god', 'things', 'those', 'to', 'weight.', 'who']
```

or you could wrap it in `sorted()` directly

```
words = sorted(sentence.expandtabs().split(' '))
>> ['All', 'come', 'god', 'things', 'those', 'to', 'weight.', 'who']
```